# I want to inject a JavaScript on iframe - http://wikipedia.com for reading the clicked event on page

Tags: java, javascript, html, cross-domain

I'm creating an http://wikipedia.com ….in index.html and I want to inject a JavaScript on iframe - http://wikipedia.com for reading the clicked event on page.
Could you suggest how to do that?

Comment: you can do that in onload event of iframe, and not in iframe content itself.

Comment: I want to inject js on iframe content like "http://wikipedia.com" header. Might be this is a cross domain problem so could you suggest me some example for the same?